# What should I know in UDP socket programming?

Tags: sockets, udp

I'm working on embedded development on UDP socket programming. What all do I need to know? How to make the connection manually? but specifying the ports and memory addresses?

Comment: Can't help without some idea of what language or environment you're working with. Check if you have a high-level connect() wrapper around UDP first.

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind?

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a connection-less transport.  There is no "connection".  You specify the destination IP/Port on each individual datagram you send.